# nginx configuration for rhodecode & redmine on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: nginx, redmine, rhodecode

I am trying to setup rhodecode + redmine on ubuntu with the following 
configuration

```
http://my_ip/redmine
```

and

```
http://my_ip/rhodecode
```

I am using nginx as the web server with redmine running on localhost:3000 
and rhodecode running on localhost:5000, somehow iam missing the point in 
configuring nginx.conf

I am able to redirect both redmine on port 3000( while testing with webrick) and rhodecode on port 5000 individually but not able to set them as

```
http://my_ip/redmine
```

and

```
http://my_ip/rhodecode
```

Following is my nginx.conf file

```
worker_processes  1;   
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/passenger-3.0.19;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p374/ruby;
upstream rhodecode {
        server  127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
    root /var/data/redmine/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    client_max_body_size      25m; # Max attachemnt size
  location /rhodecode/ {
  try_files   $uri    @rhodecode;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;

  }
 location /rhodecode {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to make subdomains `redmine.yousite.com` and `rhodecode.yoursite.com`. It's also prettier and more agile - you can easily move one of the apps to another server.

Comment: I do not want to do this as a subdomain, the question is very clear that I want to try and do it as sub URI. bounce anyone else?